# Fatal error: vtkSTLWriter.h: No such file or directory

Tags: makefile, vtk, opencv3.0

I have been trying to install OpenCV with OpenCV extra contrib modules using the given link [OpenCV_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib). I have also installed VTK which I need for project purpose. Now, when I try to run **make -j7**, it gives the following error:

```
`In file included from /home/ashutosh/opencv-3.0.0/build/modules/viz/opencv_viz_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:0:
/home/ashutosh/opencv-3.0.0/modules/viz/src/precomp.hpp:119:26: fatal error: vtkSTLWriter.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

But the file is already present in the build directory.

Searched a lot but couldn't find how to resolve. Ultimately I tried to hard code the file path in **#include** (for eg. **#include "/home/ashutosh/VTK-build/IO/Geometry/vtkSTLwriter.h"**), but then it gives some other fatal errors.

How to eliminate this bug !!

Comment: Hi Kishan, In your opencv build, where does the the cmake flag "VTK_DIR" points to? There should be written "/home/ashutosh/VTK-build". ("VTK_DIR" belongs to the advanced cmake options... if you use ccmake, press "t")

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is compatibility problem between opencv and later version of vtk (from version 7 and on), this works fine in vtk 5 and 6.

If you wish to use vtk 7 with opencv, uncheck the opencv-viz option during cmake. As opencv_viz is a 3D visvualization utility with vtk backend, the function is very limited. I recommend to use native vtk render window for full 3D rendering function.